# Seal & Calligraphy translation

Tags: seal

I was wondering if anyone could help with the translation of this seal (image has been flipped), and the characters on the side as well.

No knowledge here, but have tried handwriting the seal characters in google translate and think they may be 霄籁? Heaven Music?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seal:

> 范霞
>
> A name. Its pronunciation is dependent on where the artist comes from, so I won't give one here.

Calligraphy:

> 一九六四秊（年）七月秉昌刻于香江
>
> Carved at 香江 (location) on July 1964 by 秉昌 (another name)

Not sure about the last character「江」.

---

All of these proper nouns (names, locations) refer to multiple places/people in the East Asian cultural region, so only you (who knows the context) would be able to fully get the background information of the object.

---

Thanks @TangHo and @水巷孑蠻 who mentioned that 香江 is a poetic name for Hong Kong and that 秉昌 is the first name of a famous seal carver (陳秉昌) from Hong Kong.

In that case, 范霞 is probably a Chinese name, and is the customer who requested their seal carved by 陳秉昌.

Still no translation, but I'll provide Cantonese and Mandarin Romanisations for 范霞:

- Cantonese: Faan<sup>6</sup> Haa<sup>4</sup>
- Mandarin: Fàn Xiá

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Could you provide an english translation for 范霞?

Comment: @JeffDelich I've updated some information, but essentially I won't translate it because I think it's a name.

Comment: 香江 is a poetic nickname for Hong Kong 香港.

Comment: would it be "陳秉昌", which's a famous seal maker in hong kong, in last century. http://www.sealbank.net/m1MainFind.asp?LM=1&L1=1&L2=3&L3=0&LS=C&SRCHTXT=S2105&SK=MV

Comment: Interesting information guys, maybe it is from Hong Kong then. @水巷孑蠻 is it normal to just have their *first name*?

Comment: you mean omitting the surname? sure, if the maker has 字 or 號, he/she might omit the name totally.

Comment: 范 is a common Chinese family name. 霞 means rosy clouds or multi-coloured sunlight

Comment: @TangHo yes, I hesitated at first because 范 is also an extremely common VIetnamese surname.

Comment: @JeffDelich Tang Ho's last comment should be what you're looking for, if you want a "translation" of the name.

Comment: /faan6 haa4/ is the Jyuping of 范霞; The Cantonese Romanisations for 范霞 is Fan Ha; The Mandarin Romanisations for 范霞 is  Fan Xia

Comment: @TangHo [Jyutping is a Romanisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyutping). Anything that brings a language into a Roman script is a Romanisation.

Comment: I live in Toronto, the standard Chinese name for the city is 多倫多 or 多倫多市, but it can be shortened to 多市. The poetic nickname is 楓城 (City of Maple)

Comment: @drooze Jyutping  is a system for pronunciations;  for proper names, only English alphabets are used